# Using web technologies for UI

Tags: java, c++, html, user-interface

It fascinates me how rich the UI of web applications has become.  It is really easy to build great UIs with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but I just want to use C++ for my logic.  Is there a way to build applications in C++ or Java and use Web technologies for the UI?

I am not talking about Web Applications but standalone Applications without a web browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check my Sciter engine: http://sciter.com 
Sciter (essentially) is HTML/CSS/script embeddable engine designed specifically to be used as UI layer of applications.

Here is [Sciter integration in 21 minutes](http://sciter.com/developers/embedding-principles/) document and I'd also recommend to read [this one](http://sciter.com/sciter-ui-application-architecture/).

This application for example:

[image]

is using Sciter for its UI so HTML/CSS/and script (e.g. the map drawing) is what you actually see there.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples:

In native Win32 programming on Windows, [you can host an HTML window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is actually Internet Explorer running as a control) with your own HTML and even expose your own objects (written in C++) into Javascript.  And/or use the old ActiveX stuff.

Good example: The old "MSN Messenger" app was written entire in C++, but would host p2p games written by 3rd parties within a child window. In the picture below, the little board game is an HTML window. The rest is native Win32.

[image]

The new "modern" Windows 8 apps offer [HTML+JavaScript+WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx) as a complete development solution and can interop with C++ or C# code as the platform portion of the app.

Other people answering this question might suggestion [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) as another instance of an HTML framework that can be hosted within a native app.

Most all mobile platforms offer some sort of web browser control as part of their UI framework.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Java FX2. Can by styled with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your logic in a C++ COM Object and then consume that in a C#, which would allow you to use ASP.NET to create and display the UI

See the Com Interop introduction. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx